# Change submenu display in mobile navigation

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I would like the mobile submenu items to be shown at all times instead of having to click on them to see what is inside of a submenu. I'm not sure what the fix to this problem is...

Currently the mobile user sees just the main menu items. And they have to click on the items with subitems to be taken to the submenu.

Main 1
Main 2 > 
Main 3 
Main 4 > 
Main 5

I would like it to be like this:

Main 1
Main 2 > 
  subItem 1 
  subItem 2 
  subItem 3 
Main 3 
Main 4 > 
  subItem 1 
  subItem 2 
  subItem 3 
Main 5

This is my codepen file with the stock foundation menu.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lgoer

This is the basic structure of the menu.

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
    <ul class="title-area">

        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#">Top Bar Title</a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">

        <ul class="right">
            <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">Main Item 1</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><label>Section Name</label></li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="">Has Dropdown, Level 1</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown Options</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown Options</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Subdropdown Option</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: add the "expanded" class to your nav. the nav will default to expanded, and still be clickable to minimize

Comment: I want the submenu to show up expanded 'inside' the main menu(not requiring an additional menu). Does that make sense?

Comment: You can override the css for the dropdowns. Here is the rule:
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { 
  .top-bar-section .dropdown{
    padding: 0;
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: 99;
    display: block;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    clip:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    left:auto;
  }